# I can't type "<" with my Hungarian layout on Windows 10

Tags: windows, layout, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I use the Hungarian layout (QWERTZ) on Windows 10, and on that layout, if I press <kbd>Alt Gr + M</kbd> it should type a `<` sign. Every single key combination works, other than this. Can somebody help me out?

- I have the Hungarian HU (QWERTZ) layout, and it's set by default to that.
- I have no other layouts installed.
- My layout is set to it (for sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. I had Shadowplay on, and `alt+m` was mute, and that disallowed me from writing that symbol.